# SQL Use lookup to return max in group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, max

I'm trying to return the "max" value in a list of statuses. However, I'd like to assign a sorting value to the string values that so the maximum value is returned by my own ranking, rather than alphabetically.

Here's my code:

```
    select x.wbs1, x.wbs2, x.wbs3, x.custstatus
    from (
          select wbs1,wbs2,wbs3,custstatus=MAX(custstatus)
          from Projects_CRStatus
          where custsentdate >= 'June 1, 2001' AND custsentdate <= 'June 30, 2013'
          AND CustStatus IN ('RECEIVED AT VENDOR', 'CONFIRMATION SENT',
          'IC PENDING','CONFIRMATION RECEIVED','CANCELLED')
          group by wbs1,wbs2,wbs3 ) x
    inner join (
          select wbs1,wbs2,wbs3,custsentdate=max(custsentdate)
          from Projects_CRStatus
          group by wbs1,wbs2,wbs3) y
    on (x.wbs1=y.wbs1 and x.wbs2=y.wbs2 and x.wbs3=y.wbs3)

    ORDER BY CustEnrollmentID
```

What I'd like to do is rank the values of CustStatus so that rather than returning the top alphabetical result of CustStatus, I get the most advanced status in this order.

1. 'RECEIVED AT VENDOR'
2. 'CONFIRMATION SENT'
3. 'IC PENDING'
4. 'CONFIRMATION RECEIVED'
5. 'CANCELLED'

Comment: To clarify, I'm looking for top-ranked status within each wbs1, wbs2, wbs3 grouping in x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the word **rank**, but I'm guessing you really are asking about how to **order** your query result.  If so, you can use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CustStatus = 'RECEIVED AT VENDOR' then 1
              WHEN CustStatus = 'CONFIRMATION SENT' then 2
              WHEN CustStatus = 'IC PENDING' then 3
              WHEN CustStatus = 'CONFIRMATION RECEIVED' then 4
              WHEN CustStatus = 'CANCELLED' then 5
              ELSE 6
         END, CustEnrollmentID
```

The last entry of the CASE expression (the ELSE condition) is just for safety sake.

UPDATE: Based on your subsequent comments, here is a query to return the "top status" using the ROW_NUMBER function:

```
select wbs1, wbs2, wbs3, custstatus

from (
   select x.wbs1, x.wbs2, x.wbs3, x.custstatus,
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY x.wbs1, x.wbs2, x.wbs3 
                      ORDER BY CASE
                      WHEN x.CustStatus = 'RECEIVED AT VENDOR' then 1
                      WHEN x.CustStatus = 'CONFIRMATION SENT' then 2
                      WHEN x.CustStatus = 'IC PENDING' then 3
                      WHEN x.CustStatus = 'CONFIRMATION RECEIVED' then 4
                      WHEN x.CustStatus = 'CANCELLED' then 5
                      ELSE 6 END) as rn
   from (
      select wbs1,wbs2,wbs3,custstatus=MAX(custstatus)
      from Projects_CRStatus
      where custsentdate >= 'June 1, 2001' 
        AND custsentdate <= 'June 30, 2013'
        AND CustStatus IN ('RECEIVED AT VENDOR', 'CONFIRMATION SENT'
            ,'IC PENDING','CONFIRMATION RECEIVED','CANCELLED')
        group by wbs1,wbs2,wbs3 ) x
   inner join (
      select wbs1,wbs2,wbs3,custsentdate=max(custsentdate)
      from Projects_CRStatus
      group by wbs1,wbs2,wbs3) y
    on (x.wbs1=y.wbs1 and x.wbs2=y.wbs2 and x.wbs3=y.wbs3)
    ) z

WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I'm looking for the Top status result within the "group by". So, I'm looking for the top-ranked status for each wbs1, wbs2, wbs3 combo.

Comment: @GabeN. Oh.  What flavor of SQL are you using?  Are you familiar with the `ROW_NUMBER` windowing function?  If your database support it, that would be the way to go.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I had used the ROW_NUMBER/ Partition OVER method, but was getting multiple results.

Comment: @GabeN. So you want the "top status" for each combination of wbs1, wbs2, and wbs3 (which would be the partition)?

Answer (score 0):

Better have a table with this status codes data and join that table, so it will be possible to order by this status table column.